# Firefox extension icon on the navigation bar using the Add-on builder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How do I add an icon to Firefox that opens up a panel on click on the navigation bar. An example is the Firebug extension. The only thing that will be different, is that I want a panel to appear.

[image: Firebug Icon]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use or take a look at this toolbarbutton library:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/library/1006210/latest/