# Passing object from loaded script in firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I am developing a firefox extension that retrieves data from the webpage in the current tab. I am loading a script into the webpage when the user clicks on the overlay toolbar button which does some processing and gets information from the web page. I want to display that information in a popup window.

I am using the following api to load the script:

```
var loader = Components.classes[ "@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1" ].getService( Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader );
loader.loadSubScript("chrome://dynamonote/content/contentscript.js");
```

I need to send the object created in contentscript.js and display it in popup.html which is displayed when user clicks on the toolbar icon.

I am receiving the gBrowser is not defined error when I execute the code. The details of the code I am using is given below:

In the onCommand of the overlay, I am calling the following function:

```
var Popup = {
    showPopup: function() {
        window.open("chrome://dynamonote/content/popup.html", "dynamonote", "chrome");
    }
};
```

This shows a popup window. In the init function of popup.html which is called when the page loads, I am executing the following code:

```
        function loadContentScript() {
            Components.utils.reportError("loadContentScript() called");
            gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.loadFrameScript("chrome://dynamonote/content/contentscript.js", true);
            gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.addMessageListener("foomessage", onMessage);
            Components.utils.reportError("loadContentScript() executed");
        }
```

The following code is executed in the contentscript.js file:

```
(function() {
    Components.utils.reportError("-- content script -- ");
    var doc = content.document;

    //Do something here

    var data = {
        "time": new Date().toLocaleString()
    };
    Components.utils.reportError("-- content script -- found something");
        sendSyncMessage("foomessage", onMessage(data));
})();
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to force concepts from Chrome extensions into a classic Firefox extension, something that is far from trivial. If that's where you are coming from, the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder) might be a better choice. In particular, the packages [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/packages/addon-kit/page-mod.html) and [widget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.6/packages/addon-kit/widget.html). Either way, you seem to be mistaken about what `mozIJSSubScriptLoader` does.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to use the chrome code in firefox as well. Could you suggest a better way to do this? I cannot use the sdk apis because they dont allow me to add a toolbar button in the navigation bar like xul. Also could you tell me the difference between loadSubscript of firefox and executescript of chrome?

Comment: There is a reason why the SDK does that - extensions aren't supposed to waste space in the navigation bar any more. But, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9622212/785541.

Comment: Is there an alternate way if I want to follow the XUL way? If I need to change the current design, could you please tell me how I could approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want content scripts in a classic Firefox extension then `mozIJSSubScriptLoader` is the wrong tool - the "content script" will keep advanced privileges and likely cause security issues. You could use the [message manager](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_message_manager) instead (ignore the talk about process separation, it is irrelevant for the desktop Firefox). So to load your script into the currently selected tab you would use the following code:

```js
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager
        .loadFrameScript("chrome://dynamonote/content/contentscript.js", true);
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.messageManager.addMessageListener("foomessage", onMessage);

function onMessage(obj)
{
  alert("Received object from content script: " + obj.toSource());
}
```

Note that you should remove that message listener when it isn't needed any more. And to send a message back the content script would use code like this:

```js
sendAsyncMessage("foomessage", obj);
```

Comment: I tried out the solution but I am receiving the gBrowser is not defined error. I have updated my question with some more information. Also tried window.messageManager but that did not work either.

Comment: @quad_damage: `gBrowser` is a global variable defined in the context of the browser window. If you script is running in a different window then you need to get the browser window first. In your case it is probably as simple as `parent.gBrowser` (the script is running inside a frame in the browser window).

Comment: Sorry, I am getting the same error message "parent.gBrowser is undefined". I am loading the script from popup.html file. Popup.html is loaded when the user clicks on the toolbar icon. How can I access the gBrowser object from popup.html? I am using the following api to open the popup: `window.open("chrome://dynamonote/content/popup.html", "dynamonote", "chrome");` Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: @quad_damage: Heh... As I said, if "the script is running inside a frame". For a dialog window it will be `window.opener.gBrowser`.

Comment: Thank you Wladimir :) I had some confusions regarding the scope of the objects and their access. I was able to bring it to a working state with your suggestions. Is there a good tutorial which explains the concepts related to Firefox add-on development which I can refer to?