# Using the Toolbar Buttons library in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to add the popover icon to the area next to the URL bar, just like where the Firebug icon is. The library to do so, (recommended by a previous answer: [Firefox extension icon on the navigation bar using the Add-on builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621253/firefox-extension-icon-on-the-navigation-bar-using-the-add-on-builder))

How do I use that library with my Firefox extension? The icon is now currently at the bottom right of the FF window, and it's really small.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download this package:
https://github.com/voldsoftware/toolbarbutton-jplib

Add the `toolbarbutton.js` to your Lib folder. Also you might want to add `listen.js` and `unload+.js` as well. (The dependancies)

Add the following code in the `exports.main` function:

```
// create toolbarbutton
var tbb = toolbar.ToolbarButton({
    id: "TBB-TEST",
    label: "TBB TEST",
    onCommand: function () {
        tbb.destroy(); // kills the toolbar button
    }
});

if (require('self').loadReason == "install") {
    tbb.moveTo({
        toolbarID: "nav-bar",
        forceMove: false // only move from palette
    });
}
```

This by default adds an array of new icons to the navigation toolbar. Go figure :)